# How to write unit tests to check that methods are thread-safe

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, go

I have an object like this:

```
type Store struct {
    mutex sync.RWMutex
    data  map[string]int
}

func (s * Store) Read(key string) int, error {
    // ...
    defer s.mutex.RUnlock()
    s.mutex.RLock()
    // ...
    return val, nil
}

func (s * Store) Write(key string, value int) error {
    // ...
    defer s.mutex.Unlock()
    s.mutex.Lock()
    // ...
    return nil
}
```

How should unit-tests to look like for methods `Read` & `Write` to check that they are thread safe?

I think there are already exists patterns for cases like this, but I didn't find anything.

I read about `-race` flag:

> the race detector can detect race conditions only when they are actually triggered by running code, which means it's important to run race-enabled binaries under realistic workloads

My question is how to write unit-test which emulates realistic workloads.

Comment: Read up about the `-race` build/test flag in the [go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).

Comment: @Adrian Hi, I read about -race flag:
"the race detector can detect race conditions only when they are actually triggered by running code, which means it's important to run race-enabled binaries under realistic workloads"
My question is how to wrote unit-test which emulates realistic workloads.

Comment: By writing a test which emulates realistic workloads... there's no simple answer to that. It depends on your specific situation. You'll have to figure that part out for yourself.

Comment: Unit tests are not intended to run under realistic work loads. If you're testing realistic work loads, you are, by definition, not running unit tests. For the type of testing you want, your best bet is to run a `-race`-built binary under production-style load. But don't confuse this with unit testing, which serves an entirely different purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run your tests with the [Race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).  In short, run:

```
go test -race
```

Or to build a normal binary, such as to run on a staging server, use:

```
go build -race
```

But there are many more options, so best to read up on it :)

If your goal is to test under realistic load, your best option is to compile your code with `go build -race`, then run it under realistic load. This probably means on a staging server.  But don't confuse this with unit testing!

Unit testing is for testing units--small parts of code, usually individual functions. Load/race testing is a different beast, and requires different tools and an entirely different approach.

The fact that Go will easily run unit tests with the race detector is nice, and often catches races. But it will not, nor should not be expected to, catch *all* races, since the nature of unit test execution is entirely different from that of production execution.

Comment: Also don't forget that race conditions are but one of the possible concurrency errors. Others are deadlock, livelock and starvation. All four are difficult to eliminate by testing alone, although testing can demonstrate that their probability is below a certain threshold. More: https://www.bigbeeconsultants.uk/post/2008/four-horsemen/